# Variable inside lambda function is showing garbage value

Tags: c++, lambda, garbage-collection, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using this method in a Cocos2d X game.

```
void OpponentNode::discard(int cardNum)
{
    log("\nOpponentNode::discard <%d>\n", cardNum);
    for (int i = 0; i < vecOpponentHand.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vecOpponentHand.at(i) == cardNum)
        {
            vecOpponentHand.erase(vecOpponentHand.begin() + i);

            break;
        }
    }

    CardSprite * discardedCard;

    for (int i = 0; i < vecOpponentCards.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vecOpponentCards.at(i)->getTag() == cardNum)
        {
            discardedCard = vecOpponentCards.at(i);

            vecOpponentCards.erase(vecOpponentCards.begin() + i);

            break;
        }
    }

    log("\nOpponentNode::discard <%d>\n", cardNum);
    discardedCard->makeFaceUp();

    RotateTo * rotate = RotateTo::create(0.4 * SPEED_MULTIPLIER, 0);

    MoveTo * move = MoveTo::create(0.4 * SPEED_MULTIPLIER,
                               origin + Vec2(visibleSize.width * 0.75, visibleSize.height * 0.6));

    Spawn * spawn = Spawn::create(rotate, move, NULL);

    CallFunc * callFunc = CallFunc::create(
    [&]()
    {
        log("\nOpponentNode::discard <%d>\n", cardNum); //this one shows garbage/different value
        if (delegate)
        {
            delegate->opponentNodeDidFinishDiscard(this, cardNum);
        }

        this->removeChild(discardedCard);
    });

    discardedCard->runAction(Sequence::create(spawn, callFunc, NULL));

    log("\nOpponentNode::discard <%d>\n", cardNum);
}
```

Strangely, when I log the integer cardNum like above, I get different value from the log inside the lambda function. For example, I get "OpponentNode::discard <402>" from the top 2 logs and the bottom most log but get "OpponentNode::discard <64>" from the log inside the lambda function.

Other points:

1. The lambda block is executed last.
2. I mostly get values like 64 or garbage values like -15493456.

My guess is the integer cardNum is getting deallocated before the execution. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: You're capturing a reference to the `cardNum` parameter. I would think you want to capture that one by value.

Comment: So I shoould use something like [cardNum, &delegate, &discardedCard]() ? @AlanStokes

Comment: How about [&, cardNum]() ? @AlanStokes

Comment: The second one isn't legal. It's not clear to me what `delegate` is. Assuming it's a class member then I think you just need `[this, discardedCard, cardNum]`. Which you could abbreviate to just `[=]`, although I think the explicit one is clearer.

Comment: `discardedCard` is also a local variable so you don't want to capture it by reference either.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Using [=]() solved it for me. But [&, cardNum]() also works. You can copy paste your comments and I'll mark it as the answer. @AlanStokes

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're capturing a reference to the `cardNum` parameter. I would think you want to capture that one by value.

It's not clear to me what `delegate` is. Assuming it's a class member then I think you just need `[this, discardedCard, cardNum]`. Which you could abbreviate to just `[=]`, although I think the explicit one is clearer.